# Running Django development server on a remote machine using putty. How to run the dev server?

Tags: python, django, linux, putty, remote-server

I am not running the development server on my local box, but `sshing` to another machine.

I tried change where the development server is being run by locating the ip address 
(use the ifconfig command and look for the address associated with eth0), and running the dev server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver <ipaddress>:8000
```

but when I type the URL `http://<ipaddress>:8000` in a browser I get `cannot connect to the website`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try opening the port in the firewall?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried once, and I can only open `<ipaddress>`, not `<ipaddress>:8000`. Maybe I did it wrong. Can you explain the proper steps?

Comment: 1. Run your firewall configuration tool. 2. Open incoming port 8000/tcp.

Comment: I mean the firewall configuration tool on the server.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I simply tried  `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT`. It does not solve the problem. What else can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of typing in your ipaddress, use 0.0.0.0, so that any other ip address can connect to your server.  And then yes, as others have mentioned, you must open port 8000 for incoming connections.

Comment: This helped out a lot! I couldn't figure out how my server could run from the server running it and not remotely. I had to allow the port in my ufw config. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

Use [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) via ssh. The specifics might be different in your case, but a good guide is up at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding. Hope that helps!